# How to change category of an app during an update?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, categories

I'm updating my app, but i cannot find where to change the primary category. Itunes connect let me change everything but not the categories (primary or second). Any ideas?

Comment: Technically no. He was asking IF it was possible, while i'm asking HOW :) Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to click the "Edit" link next to the "Version Information" heading.

Comment: thank you!! Was kinda invisible to me ^^'

Comment: Yeah, that page is oddly hard to navigate :-)